# Page context in SignalR typescript client

Tags: jquery, typescript, signalr

In a typescript SignalR client how do I access the class scope during return from an async hub event or promise, for example:

**Client.ts**

```
class Client {
    private _elementId: string;

    constructor(elementId: string){
       this._elementId = elementId
    }

    $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function () {
            $("#" + this._elementId).html("Connection Id" + $.connection.hub.id);
           })
        .fail((err) => {
            $("#" + this._elementId).html("Error occured"); 
           });

    // handlers - methods called by the SignalR Hub
    $.connection.myHub.client.notification = function (message) {
        $("#" + this._elementId).html(message);
    };

}
```

In promises for both the `start` and `notification` methods above the scope of `this` has been lost, so I can't access the `_elementId` member variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an arrow function `() => {}` on the `done` handler to maintain lexical scope similar to how you do with the `fail` handler. This will allow `this` to refer the class instance inside the handler:

```
class Client {
    private _elementId: string;

    constructor(elementId: string){
       this._elementId = elementId
    }

    $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(() => {
            $("#" + this._elementId).html("Connection Id" + $.connection.hub.id);
        })
        .fail((err) => {
            $("#" + this._elementId).html("Error occured"); 
        });

    // handlers - methods called by the SignalR Hub
    $.connection.myHub.client.notification = function (message) {
        $("#" + this._elementId).html(message);
    };

}
```

Here is a simple [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.bar()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo()%3A%20Promise%3Cvoid%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20resolve()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.foo().then(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.greeting)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20Greeter(%22world%22)%3B) in action. Notice the message in the console.

Hopefully that helps!